# Woocommerce - change image issue

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic

I have an issue with a picture on your product page. It is on following page ["productpage-bizsys"](https://bizsys.dk/produkt/dankortrulle-bonrulle-billig-verifone-yomani-xenta-57x25-meter/), where I want to change the image. I have made the picture in same dimensions as the present picture, but when I change it, it look like this (only showing the half of the picture): 
[image]

Is there anyone who can help with the issue - maybe there have been someone who had the same problem?.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the page lives in the template parts of the theme folder. Can you locate product.page.php or content.product.php file?

The easiest solution is navigate to the WordPress UI interface --> Pages --> "product page", choose a feature image. This product image looks like a dynamic feature image you can easily change.